# How to fix unequal label size in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have set equal auto-layout constraints fore both the label but, the text on the left label appears to shrink while the label on the right displays the text according to the layout constraints. Could anyone please let me know how can I fix this issue? Thanks for the help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Keshu has answered, you have minimum Font size enabled. I would, however, suggest taking a look at your constraints do you perhaps have leading on the first label, a trailing on the second, and horizontal constraint between them?

If this is so, on devices smaller than the device size of the Xib you used to design this, AutoLayout will try to shrink one of the labels to meet your constraints.

Comment: Yes I have exactly the same constraints mentioned by you!

Comment: Do I need to remove them? As I have set them differently for various iOS devices

Comment: Not necessarily, it would depend on how you want your view to react. Play around with your constraints. Try removing the horizontal between the two labels and see how it reacts. Or you could try changing the horizontal to a "less than or equal to constraint" to allow it to be smaller on smaller devices.

Comment: Thanks I was able to fix it by altering the horizontal constraint between the two labels!

Answer (score 1):

In `AutoShrink` - Set it to `Fixed Font Size` instead of `Minimum Font Size`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Let me try that!

Comment: If I set it to a fixed font size the text is not shown completely. It is displayed as SA....

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 thats because the text is not able to fit itself in the given width constraint.. decrease the font size to 30 for both and then try